# Confusion about direction of gravity (exercise)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, friction

[image]

I am trying to solve this question from the 2017 F=MA exam. Here is what I did:

By taking the two slopes, the acceleration when the puck is going up the ramp is $-2$ and when it is coming down, it is $\frac23$.

I rewrote this using Newton's second law, taking the vertical component of gravity and friction:

Going up: $-2m = -mg \sin θ - μmg \cos θ$

Going down: $\frac23m = -mg \sin θ + \mu mg \cos θ$

After doing this and solving for the friction coefficient, I got 0.15(B) as my answer. However, this is not the correct answer. I looked around the web and found this solution, which results in the correct answer, 0.29(D): https://kevinshuang.com/2017/10/20/2017-problem-19/

It appears that he changes the sign of the force of gravity; when the puck is going up, gravity is $-g$, and when it is coming down, it is $g$. Why is this, and what did I do wrong?

Comment: The graph may use a $v$ on the axis, but it is a speed/time graph, not a velocity/time graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When going up, the downward acceleration (sum of friction and tangential part of gravity (both same direction)) is negative $(-2)$. Thus you are considering up as positive. Thus $g$ is negative.

When going down, the downward acceleration is positive $(\frac{2}{3})$. Thus you are considering down as positive. Thus $g$ is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the second equation which you wrote went wrong . 
It should be - 
**mgsin30 - kinetic friction = mass×acceleration**

Although I'm confused that value of g is isn't taken what actually it is i.e. 9.8m/sec/sec .

Answer (score 1):

The graph is slightly confusing because with the $v$, it appears to be a velocity vs time graph.  As such, you might expect to read the acceleration as the slope.

But as mentioned in the problem, it is a speed vs velocity graph.  The puck is accelerating downward in both phases.  So the acceleration ratio between the two situations is 3:1, not -3:1